# Ruby: how to perform lazy regex matching?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is a following up question regarding [Lazy (ungreedy) matching multiple groups using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885283/lazy-ungreedy-matching-multiple-groups-using-regex). I try to use the method but not very successful.

I grab a string from gitlab API and try to extract all the repos. The name of repo follows the format of "https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git".

So far, if I try this, it works OK.

```
gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\//)
```

But to add name wildcard is tricky, I use the method from the previous question:

```
gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\/(.*?)\.git\"/)
```

It says to use (.*?) for lazy matching, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It returns `[["xxx"]]`, isn't that expected?

Comment: I prefer to return https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git, any way to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you could use `(?: ... )` if the matching pattern is more complex than just `.*?`, otherwise just leave off the parentheses

Comment: Tip: If you're using `/` inside your regular expression the `%r{...}` notation makes it a lot less messy since those won't have to be escaped.

Comment: Nice tip, I don't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have the following string:

```
gitlab_str = "\"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git\""
```

The following RegEx will return `[["xxx"]]`, which is expected:

```
gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\/(.*?)\.git\"/)
```

Because you had the `(.*?)`. Note the parenthesis, so only what's inside the parenthesis will be returned.
If you want to return the whole string matched, you can just remove the parenthesis:

```
gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\/.*?\.git\"/)
```

This will return:

```
["\"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git\""]
```

It also works for multiple occurrences:

```
> gitlab_str = "\"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git\" and \"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/yyy.git\""
> gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\/.*?\.git\"/)

=> ["\"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx.git\"", "\"https://gitlab.example.com/foo/yyy.git\""]
```

Finally, if you want to remove the `https://` part from the resulting matches, then just wrap everything but that part with `()` in the RegEx:

```
gitlab_str.scan(/\"https\:\/\/(gitlab\.example\.com\/foo\/.*?\.git)\"/)
```

Comment: I see, previously I thought it doesn't work because it would also match things like "https://gitlab.example.com/foo/xxx, name:"...", path: "...".........git". In other words, there is garbage between "xxx" and ".git". So instead of allowing (.*), I should restrict the alphabet set. Thanks!

Comment: If the URL has cases where it doesn't end with `.git"` then this RegEX will be a problem, so you'd need a more sophisticated matching, like limiting the alphabet instead of using a wildcard, or expecting a `"` before a `.git`, etc...

Comment: Thanks, for this case, I replace .*? with [^,]+ because comma should not appear in repo name, which works pretty good.